# How to convert anchored position in unity RectTransform to other anchored position?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I want to make a responsive image cropper in the canvas.
But the main problem is that I cannot find any function in Unity API that help me to convert anchored position to another anchored position with deferent anchor.
So is there any method for that?

Answer (score 1):

RectTransform.anchoredPosition is the property you're looking for.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html

Comment: You misunderstood my question I want to convert RectTransform.anchoredPosition to other anchor, I mean if there is a method I gave it the current anchored position with it's anchor and the destination anchor to get the anchor position relative to the distention anchor.